# What is the format for device filters in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

So the Session config proto has a device_filters option, with the comment:

```
// When any filters are present sessions will ignore all devices which do not
  // match the filters. Each filter can be partially specified, e.g. "/job:ps"
  // "/job:worker/replica:3", etc.
```

Does anyone have concrete explanation of the format? For example, I want to exclude /gpu:0 as an option because I use it for running other models.

I've tried

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.device_filters.append('/gpu:1')
config.device_filters.append('/cpu:0')
with tf.Session(config=config):
    # Do stuff
```

But I'm still getting ops allocated to gpu 0. I don't want to override the devices on a per-op basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ConfigProto.device_filters` field is currently ignored by TensorFlow, although it is intended to support your use case in future. If you want to achieve the same end of running ops on `/gpu:1` and `/cpu:0`, you can do that as follows, using "soft placement":

```
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
  # Build your model in this with context. All nodes will get the
  # device "/gpu:1".

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)):
  # Execute your mode in this with context.
  # Soft placement will use /gpu:1 for GPU-compatible ops, and /cpu:0
  # for CPU-only ops.
```

Comment: any timeline for the implementation of this mechanism?  A common use-case will be assigning everything to one of the GPUs in a multi-GPU setup (i.e. one `train` and one `eval` job)

Comment: It is implemented for Distributed TensorFlow, so if you create a `tf.train.Server` and then connect your `tf.Session` to that server, you can use the option.  Alternative, you can use the [`tf.ConfigProto.gpu_options.visible_device_list`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4b136d9fc4de0a53c17e336965f8884fd36168a8/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L42) option to specify that a `tf.Session` use only a subset of the (local) GPUs.