# How to specify which device to use for saved model

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I have a model trained and saved with python tensorflow.
Now I want to perform prediction in a c++ application.

I am loading the model like this (on Tensorflow 1.3.1):

```
std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::SavedModelBundle> bundle(new tensorflow::SavedModelBundle());

tensorflow::Status status = tensorflow::LoadSavedModel(
  tensorflow::SessionOptions(),
  tensorflow::RunOptions(),
  modelPath,
  { tensorflow::kSavedModelTagServe },
  bundle.get());
```

How can I specify which device this model should run on?
Specificly, I want to be able to force a model to run on cpu rather than gpu.

Currently, I am doing this by setting the environment variable CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1, but this does not allow me to e.g. have one model on gpu and another one on cpu at the same time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The session options allow you to configure which devices will be visible in your session, so you can prevent a GPU device from being created as follows:

```
tensorflow::SessionOptions options;
auto* device_count = options.config.mutable_device_count();
device_count->insert({"CPU", 1});
device_count->insert({"GPU", 0});
```

Then use `options` in place of `tensorflow::SessionOptions()` in the call to `LoadSavedModel()`.

Comment: I didnt know that. Great!

Comment: How to do the same in TensorFlow 2.3 C++?

Comment: I receive the following error while doing so: CMakeFiles/example.dir/exam.cpp.o: In function `google::protobuf::internal::MapField<tensorflow::ConfigProto_DeviceCountEntry_DoNotUse, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, (google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)9, (google::protobuf::internal::WireFormatLite::FieldType)5, 0>::MutableMap()':
exam.cpp:(.text._ZN6google8protobuf8internal8MapFie

Answer (score 0):

You could set the following in the session options but this is also session wide:

```
tensorflow::SessionOptions options = TF::SessionOptions();
options.config.mutable_gpu_options()->force_gpu_compatible();
```

If you want to have it per model or variable specifically, you should use the with specifiers while building the model, which is then stored when serializing it as a protobuf graph:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0], shape=[2, 1])
```

or:

```
with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0], shape=[2, 1])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not change anything. Although using force_gpu_compatible(), the model is still running on the gpu. Is this setting perhaps ignored by tensorflow like [device_filters being ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33685318/1901491)?

Comment: You mean the model is still running on the cpu I assume? Maybe it is ignored or you have used operators that are only supported on the GPU? I would other suggest as written above to set the device directly on model creation.

Comment: No, the model runs on gpu and I want it to run on cpu as said in the question. Setting the devices during model creation would mean I need a gpu and a cpu version of each model...

Comment: The [`force_gpu_compatible` option](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f7cbb757cf51143a1c7d9db5a812ac165941adf4/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L75) doesn't actually affect the placement of ops on different devices, but rather it affects the *allocation* of tensors. Setting it to true will place all CPU-device tensors in CUDA-pinned memory, which can lead to a performance improvement in some settings.